# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, in if but never work

Tags: swift, core-data, null, alert

I Have a problem with this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

So i have a Alert with a `DatePicker` and when i tap the Done Button it´s save the `NSDate` in `CoreData`. 
In this line `AlertView.DatePicker.date = newDateEvery.picturedate!` it´s cum the Error so i make that with the `if newDateEvery.picturedate != nil {}` the Error is away but it isn´t never != nil so it save anything. 
Have anything an idea what i can do there ?? or an another way to get the fatal error to lead away?? Thanks for your Help :).

addAction from Alert "Done" Button :

```
alert.addAction(SimpleAlert.Action(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
  let newDateEvery = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Everyday", inManagedObjectContext: self.mgdContext) as! Everyday
  if self.Segmentedevery.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    if newDateEvery.picturedate != nil {
      let AlertView = DateAlertController()
      AlertView.DatePicker.date = newDateEvery.picturedate!
      print("save in picture")
    }
  } else if self.Segmentedevery.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    if newDateEvery.videodate != nil {
      let AlertView = DateAlertController()
      AlertView.DatePicker.date = newDateEvery.videodate!
      print("save in video")
    }
  }
  do {
    try self.mgdContext.save()
    print("Save")
  } catch {
    print("Error")
  }
}))
```

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with this initializer: `DateAlertController()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `picturedate` element of `newDateEvery` is of optionnal type.

Imagine optionnal type as a wrapped box, containing either something (your var) or nothing (nil).
The way to unwrap it is the following :

```
if let safeVar = newDateEvery.picturedate {
    AlertView.DatePicker.date = safeVar
}
```

This way you make sure that the box contain something.

What you did here `AlertView.DatePicker.date = newDateEvery.picturedate!` is called forced unwrapping. You said to swift "don't worry, the box contain something". So if it's empty at runtime -> crash.

Then by doing `if newDateEvery.picturedate != nil {}` you checked if the box was nil. Actually the box is not nil, it's just a box.

Comment: But when i make that he don´t take the code in {}. So when i say `if let safeVar= newDateEvery.picturedate { print("Code Works") }` it´s print nothing.

Comment: It's because the box is empty. Debug your code, put a break point on the if, and do step by step mode. Check where the execution pointer go

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Swift 2.0+ you can do the following:

```
guard let safeVar = newDateEvery.picturedate else {
    //safeVar is nil, do something in response
}
AlertView.DatePicker.date = safeVar
//Do any other work
```

The `else` block will be executed if safeVar is nil. Additional information about `guard` can be found in the [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html)

Comment: I was wondering, for redability, are guard supposed to stay in the first lines of the functions?

Comment: Totally. It makes your code more readable, you know when you have values and where you handle it if you don't, as well as more maintainable.

Comment: Yhea I already use them, but only for fonction wide scope variable, not niched vars scoped inside if. Just preference I guess8